# How to show one post content in another post content which has same terms?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, meta-query

I am trying to solve a problem for last two weeks but still I haven’t not found  any solution yet.
Let me explain my problem first:
I have two custom post types: one is `football_fixture` and second is `football_league`.
These two CPT have two common taxonomies: one is “`competition`” and second is ‘’`session`”.These two taxonomies have terms also; for example: laliga, EPL, Seria and 2016-17, 2015-16 respectively.
Now what I want :
In my `football_league`  post , I want to show the content of `football_fixture` according to following condition:
1)In `football_league` post If  I select term of competition taxonomy  and session taxonomy then it will show only the content of `football_fixture` posts which has those terms.
See image for more explanation:
[image]
Suppose, I have published 5  football_fixture  posts  with competition terms “`laliga`” and `session` term “`2026-17`”.
Now if I published a `football_league` post with `competition` terms “`laliga`” and `session` term “`2026-17`” then it will show those 5 `football_fixture`’s 5 post.
Is it possible?
I used following codes:

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem myself:
What I did is:
First created **`single-football_league.php template`** where i placed following codes:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                    <?php get_template_part( 'content-parts/content', 'league' ); ?>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Second:
In **`content-league.php`**, I placed following codes, and it works:

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, array('competition', 'session') );
$term_slugs = wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'slug' );    
 $season = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'session' );
$season_slugs = wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'slug' ); 
$args = array(
        'post_type' => array( 'football_fixture' ), // profile and letter are CPTs
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                'taxonomy' => 'competition',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $term_slugs
                ),
               array (
              'taxonomy' => 'session',
              'terms' => $season_slugs,
              'field' => 'slug')
            )   
    );
```